# batch script to find last two days from the current date

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am in a project where I need to find all files which are two days lesser than the current date. How can we achieve this using a batch script in Windows?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

I have previously misunderstood the question. Here is the updated answer.

The syntax is a little bit different for different OS.

```
forfiles /d +2      (Windows Server 2008)
forfiles -d+2       (Windows 2000)
```

In case there is no such command in your OS, here is a **[link](http://www.petri.co.il/download_free_reskit_tools.htm)** for downloading the FORFILES command.

You can even specify what you want to do for those files. Type `forfiles /?` or `forfiles -?` for help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do with the files after you have found them but you could use the [ForFiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551(WS.10).aspx) command.